# Issue with LibreSSL on my MacBookwith macOS Mojave

Tags: mojave, performance

I am having issue for some time with my MacBookPro.

The issue is that my MBP is having some occasional hiccups (when it freezes for few minutes and showing rainbow beachball and then after few minutes it starts to work again) but as side effect I found that after that my computer cannot connect to sites via SSL with following error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/': LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443
```

It resolves only when I reboot my MBP.

I completely reinstalled macOS on this computer and it still persists. Has anyone experienced something similar and knows the solution?

Comment: I don't experience that. But I'm able to deal with GitHub with no LibreSSL at all, so I think there should be non glitchy alternatives to what you might be doing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987512/ssl-connect-ssl-error-syscall-in-connection-to-github-com443 almost the same question on SO. See proxy settings as one answer suggests. Another talks about host resolving.

Comment: I will add some extra information here:

I have Kaspersky antivirus installed. Could it be a culprit?

It works initially and then after some time it starts behave badly with a symptoms that I described in original question above.

Comment: I think it may be Kaspersky as I just closed my hunged KAV and I was able to get SSL connection to GitHub. It may be coincidence but I will keep my eye on it.